# Finding position of data in the array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array, say,

```
$array = Array("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5");
```

I want to find the position of these names in the array.

I want to return 0 for `Name1` and 2 for `Name3`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `array_search`. BTW have you ever tried to look at http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$key = array_search('Name1', $array);
```

Ref: [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos = array_search("Name3", $array);
```

Should be what you are looking for, note that to be safe, result checking should be using === (three equal signs) so that those returning 0 (if you are looking for thing in the first element) is also checked for type when you are comparing them in an if statement

```
if(array_search($name, $array) === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
<?php
   $array = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5");
   $searchValue = "Name1";
   $keys = array_keys($array, $searchValue);

   // test it
   print_r($keys);
?>
```